# UIView always has ambiguous layout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, ios8

I put only one label in my view and added four constraints like this.
[image]

Then I wore these code:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    for (UIView *aView in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([aView hasAmbiguousLayout]) {
            NSLog(@"View Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(aView.frame));
            NSLog(@"%@", [aView class]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [aView constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:1]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [aView constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]);

            [aView exerciseAmbiguityInLayout];
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it won't have any ambiguous layout, however I saw these output.

```
2015-07-28 17:03:05.087 MyApp[1865:25321] View Frame {{8, 76}, {42, 21}}
2015-07-28 17:03:05.088 MyApp[1865:25321] UILabel
2015-07-28 17:03:05.088 MyApp[1865:25321] (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b445f20 V:|-(76)-[UILabel:0x7b449c70'Label']   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x7b449b00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b449350 V:[UILabel:0x7b449c70'Label'(21)]>"
)
2015-07-28 17:03:05.088 MyApp[1865:25321] (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b443890 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7b449c70'Label']   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x7b449b00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b448de0 H:[UILabel:0x7b449c70'Label'(42)]>"
)
```

I have iOS7.1 and 8.4 simulator installed, but those output ONLY appear in iOS8.4.

Is there something I was doing wrong or it's just a bug?

thanks :->)

Comment: If there is an Ambiguous Layout the storyboard will tell you about that

Comment: Does this cause any practical problems or does it only show these warnings? On a project I'm working on XCode 6, there are ALWAYS these kinds of ambiguous layout warnings. Even after I corrected them one by one, they still reappear after some time, but have no effect on my UI whatsoever. My suggestion would be to just ignore them if they aren't causing any major problems.

Comment: @Varun Naharia I'm using xib, not storyboard and it didn't appear any warnings or errors when I'm editing.

Comment: @halileohalilei It didn't cause any practical problems in layout, but I still think it's quite awful to see these information.

Comment: @GetToSet It is. But I believe them to be a bug of XCode. Mostly when I correct these warnings, the ambiguities are caused of 0.5 misplacements or so. Nothing important really.

Comment: yes in xib also it's shows any missing or an extra constraints in it in the Document Outline Window

Answer (score 0):

You can view any Ambiguous Layout if is there any in the Document Outline Window

Update :
[image: fig]

You can see an yellow arrow side to the view that shows any missing constraints, when you click on that arrow it will show you the message.

Comment: But I can't see any warnings or errors on my outline window. It's quite clean.

Comment: Yeah but mine appears like this

Comment: your Image showing only main window not the Document Outline Window, You have to click rectangle bottom left side of the UI Window

Comment: Then there is everything correct. there something else that is showing that message

Comment: Yeah I thought there's everything well but I can still receive those message when the app is running.

Comment: these message only showing applied constraints on the label not the missing or any Ambiguous layout if you comment out the NSLog in your code you won't see any message